# Problems calculating the degree of the antipodal map using the integral definition of degree.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $f:S^n\to S^n$, $f(p)=-p$. I'm trying to prove that $deg(f)=(-1)^{n+1}$ using the following definition of degree:

$$\int_{S^n}f^*\omega = deg(f)\int_{S^n}\omega \hspace{10pt} \forall \omega \in \Omega^n(S^n).$$

Let $\{x_0,...,x_n\}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. So we can take $\omega = dx_1 \wedge ... \wedge dx_n|_{S^n}\in \Omega^n(S^n)$. Then

$$\int_{S^n} f^* \omega = \int_{S^n} d(-x_1) \wedge ... \wedge d(-x_n) = (-1)^n\int_{S^n} \omega \implies deg(f)=(-1)^n$$

What am I missing here? I appreciate any help.

Comment: There's no contradiction here: since $\int_{S^n} dx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_n = 0$, this computation ($0 = \deg(f) \cdot 0$) tells you nothing about the degree of $f$.   Try another differential form.

Comment: Isn’t the form you are integrating a boundary, so it will integrate to 0?

Comment: Ah yeah. Thanks! I missed that.